# How do I sort a date of format mm/yy with the jquery tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a table wherein one of the columns displays the date in the mm/yy format viz. 12/08, 01/09, 02/08, etc.

How do I implementing sorting on this column with the jQuery tablesorter (http://tablesorter.com) so that the dates are appropriately sorted?

Using the default date format does not work as it expects a date of three elements (mm/dd/yy such as 01/06/09).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html for information about custom parsers.

You need to do a text sort but with the year and month switched. You could use a format function similar to this:

```
format: function(s) {
    date = s.split(/\//);
    return date[1] + date[0];
},
```

There may be a simpler way, but that is what I was able to find in my quick search through the documentation.